# VueJS Datepicker: how to dynamically disable dates?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2

I'm implementing the [vue-hotel-datepicker](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker) library into my project and I wish to dynamically add dates to the [disabledDates](https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker#disableddates) property after making an ajax call, but my implementation does not seem to work. When I debug using the Vue devtools, I can clearly see that the `disabledDates` array contains my correct dates, it just **does not render them** as 'disabled'. It works when I hardcode those dates.

**Template:**

```
<datepicker
     :disabledDates="disabledDates" 
     :firstDayOfWeek="1"                
    >
</datepicker>
```

**JS:**

```
data() {
   return {
      disabledDates: this.fetchBookedDates() //contains correct data, see screenshot below
    }
},
methods: {
    fetchBookedDates() {
       window.fetch(Routing.generate('bookings'))
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(data => this.disabledDates = data['period'])
         .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      }
}
```

Debugging steps:
The Vue devtools shows the `disabledDates` from my fetch call immediately upon page load, but all dates are still enabled on my datepicker:

[image]

**Hardcoded (works):**

When I hardcode a couple of dates, it **does** display my dates as 'disabled':

```
data() {
   return {
     disabledDates: ['2019-02-03', '2019-02-04']
    }
}
```

And I get the same results in the Vue devtools as when I add them dynamically (also on page load):

[image]

What is wrong about my implementation and how should I fix this?

**EDIT**

The `HotelDatePicker` component is generated from my library, which contains the `disabledDates` property that I need to overwrite. This screenshot is the result from dynamically adding the `disabledDates` via an ajax call as explained above. After my ajax call, both components (Datepicker and HotelDatePicker) have the same `disabledDates`, containing the same data. But my dates are not rendered as being 'disabled' (only when I hardcode them)
[image]

Comment: Sounds like that component might not care if `disabledDates` are dynamic and to re-render them as disabled. Can you to a simple `setTimeout` function in your component which will update the `disabledDates` with hardcoded values to confirm this.

Comment: @thefallen You are correct. Does this mean there is no way of showing my disabledDates at all? Thank you.

Comment: You might have to fetch the disabled dates somewhere above, before rendering this component, like passing them from the html or force the component to be destroyed and re-render when you fetch the array with the disabled dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a quick look at the source - that component doesn't support a dynamic change of that prop.

It parses the content of the prop once, in `beforeMount`:

https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker/blob/master/src/components/DatePicker.vue#L529

And doesn't care about subsequent changes.

It could be fixed by adding a `watch` on that prop to call that parse method again, or turning it into a computed prop instead.

But without such a change it simply doesn't work.

edit: a hack to make it work could look like this:

```
<datepicker
     :disabledDates="disabledDates" 
     :firstDayOfWeek="1"
     :key="disabledDates.length"               
    >
</datepicker>
```

Which will force Vue to destroy and re-create the component when the length of the array changes. If yoiu change the array without changing length, it wouldn't work though with this choice of key.

Comment: Very smart with the key thing.

Comment: I have used the same code as in my question, but added your `key` thing. The result is `Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.disabledDates is undefined`

Comment: Well you have to have the `disabledDates` property initialized as an empty array in `data, much like @thefallen demonstrated in his reply, which is also correct in its own way - your original code didn't propertly initialize things.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are fethching them you don't need to add a property `:disabledDates="disabledDates"` on your tag. For the request you can use the mounted hook to send the request when the component is mounted and then to update the disabled dates when data is received:

```
data() {
  return {
    disabledDates: []
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.fetchBookedDates();
},
methods: {
  fetchBookedDates() {
    const that = this;

    window.fetch(Routing.generate('bookings'))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => that.disabledDates = data['period'])
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. I have updated my question with more info.